Making a tree diagram up and down child nodes growing using Forest
i have been working on Forest trying to create a problem tree using Overleaf, but most info handle one side growing branches. I want to replicate the attached image and i've tryied many ways but anyone seems to work. Also i don't know why i am not able to put a line brake on the node boxes (for fitting purposes) and the connection lines go trough the central node line.
Is it possible to get some similar to the example? I don't really care to much about the shapes and color, just want to make it acceptable and readable to put it on my thesis.
Here is what i have done so far:
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{forest}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={ 
    minimum width=2.5em,
    inner sep=20pt,
    anchor=center,
    if level=1{no edge, before computing xy={l=0,s=0}}{draw}
    }
    [Ausencia de un proceso de manufactura Aditiva con acero inoxidable en la Universidad del Valle
    [, for tree={grow'=north}
    [Restricción en recursos pedagógicos
    [Atraso académico
        [Falencias en la formación profesional]
    ]
    [Incapacidad para materializar soluciones óptimas e innovadoras.
        [Baja competitividad de la Universidad respecto a otras instituciones frente a problemas en la industria]
    ]
    [Pérdida de interés por parte de los estudiantes
        [Deserción estudiantil]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    [, 
    [Preferencia por enseñanza de métodos tradicionales.
    [Aún con sus limitaciones, los métodos convencionales predominan en la industria.]
    ]
    [Alto costo en equipos de MA en metales.
    [La MA en metales opera en instituciones de I+D o industria especializada.]
    ]
    [Limitación de materiales y equipos en la universidad.
    [Pocos recursos destinados para adquisición de nuevas tecnologías.]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{document}

This is the target:

And this is the code output so far:


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code example compatible. It contain an error ! Missing number, treated as zero

well, that diagram is not a tree :-) so you cannot draw it with forest without ... dancing a bit.

This provides the structure of the not-tree. I assume you can format it as desired, since you said you weren't bothered about the colours etc. in the original. (Personally, I think the image is not very attractive and overly fussy, but tastes differ.)
I did, however, have to fix the error in your original code.

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728370/
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering}p{#1}@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    minimum width=2.5em,
    draw,
    font=\sffamily,
    anchor=center,
    if level=1{%
      coordinate,
      for descendants/.process={Ow{name}{%
          forked edge,
          align=C{50mm},
          tier/.process={Ow{level}{#1-##1}},
        }%
      },
    }{},
  },
  [Ausencia de un proceso de manufactura Aditiva con acero inoxidable en la Universidad del Valle,
    [, for tree={%
        grow'=north,
      },
      before computing xy={%
        l/.process={ OOw2+d{!u.max y}{!u.y}{#2-#1} },
      },
      [Restricción en recursos pedagógicos
        [Atraso académico
          [Falencias en la formación profesional]
        ]
        [Incapacidad para materializar soluciones óptimas e innovadoras.
          [Baja competitividad de la Universidad respecto a otras instituciones frente a problemas en la industria]
        ]
        [Pérdida de interés por parte de los estudiantes
          [Deserción estudiantil]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [, before computing xy={%
        l/.process={ OOw2+d {!u.min y}{!u.y}{#2-#1} },
      },
      [Preferencia por enseñanza de métodos tradicionales.
        [{Aún con sus limitaciones, los métodos convencionales predominan en la industria.}]
      ]
      [Alto costo en equipos de MA en metales.
        [La MA en metales opera en instituciones de I+D o industria especializada.]
      ]
      [Limitación de materiales y equipos en la universidad.
        [Pocos recursos destinados para adquisición de nuevas tecnologías.]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Thank you very much, that's exactly what i'm toward to, i can work on it right now.
